# For loop in calculated table PowerBI DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to do something similar to a for loop but in DAX code within a calculated table.

I have the following code in my calculated table so far (shortened for the purpose of posting this question). It is doing a lot of things, but I have hardcoded a check (at two points) to make sure the shops have a code of "100". I can't do this in a normal filter, because it only applies to certain stages of the code, not all of it.

```
`ShopsTable = 
VAR PrimaryShops =
    CALCULATETABLE (
        VALUES ( 'shops'[_id] ),
        'shops'[code] = "100",
        'shops'[phase] = "Primary"
    )
VAR PrimaryEmployees =
    CALCULATETABLE (
        DISTINCT ( VALUES ( 'employees_shops'[employee] ) ),
        'employees_shops'[phase] = "Primary" &&
        'employees_shops'[shop] IN PrimaryShops 
    )
VAR SecondaryEmployeeIDs =
    CALCULATETABLE (
        VALUES ( 'employees_shops'[employee] ),
        'employees_shops'[phase] = "Secondary" &&
        'employees_shops'[employee] IN PrimaryShops
    )
VAR SecondaryShops =
    CALCULATETABLE (
        VALUES ( 'employees_shops'[shop] ),
        'employees_shops'[phase] = "Secondary" &&
        'employees_shops'[employee] IN SecondaryEmployeeIDs
    )
VAR SecondaryShopsWithCounts =
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        SUMMARIZE (
            SecondaryShops, 
            'employees_shops'[shop], 
            "name", MAXX ( FILTER ( 'shops', 'shops'[_id] = 'employees_shops'[shop] ), 'shops'[name] ),
        "type",
            IF (
                MAXX ( FILTER ( 'shops', 'shops'[_id] = 'employees_shops'[shop] ), 'shops'[code] ) = "100",
                "SecondaryInGroup",
                "SecondaryOutOfGroup"
            ),
        "_id", MAXX ( FILTER ( 'shops', 'shops'[_id] = 'employees_shops'[shop] ), 'schools'[_id] )
    )
RETURN
    SecondaryShopsWithCounts`
```

This code works perfectly well when I hardcode the numbers in like this. However, I was wondering if there is a way to loop through a range of numbers.

I have a separate table (not connected to anything else in my power bi dataset) called codes with the following data:

```
Code     Name
100      Shop1
200      Shop2
300      Shop3
400      Shop4
500      Shop5
```

Is it possible to run the code in a loop for each one of these records in the codes table, then collate the findings in a final table, with an extra column to say what shop name they ran with.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to replace the MAXX() functions with LOOKUPVALUE() if you are only expecting one matching value. Will be more efficient and cleaner.

It sounds like you are wanting to evaluate the shop code related to the employee's shop. If you are wanting to hard-code what to do for each shop-type, try using a SWITCH() function. This will perform one action based on the matching code.

If you are wanting to evaluate all shop-types and aggregate (e.g., concatenate the matching names), you will want to use one of the aggregation functions, depending on what you want to do with the matching data.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/aggregation-functions-dax

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I dont want to hard code the values, i want it to automatically loop through every shop record in the codes table (replacing the hardcoded '100' with the unique shop code each time). I then want to put all the results in one table (with the shop name/code in a seperate column), so I can then filter it on my report page, rather than having a separate hardcoded table for each one. If you could help with the code I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Do you have an Excel mockup of what you are wanting to see? If you are just wanting to display the shop name for each code, it might be best to connect the codes table to the shops table via a relationship so you can directly use the shop name in the visual.

Comment: It's kind of complicated, but I'll try and explain. I have a shop codes table. For each code, I want to find all the primary shops with that code, get all the employees from those shops, and then find all the secondary shops those employees are also linked to. But the secondary shops don't have to have the same code. I'm then returning a table of all the secondary shops with a column saying if they are in the same group (code) or not. I need to do this for every shop code in the codes table, but so far have only been able to hardcode the shop code each time.

Comment: Secondary shops may appear in more than one groups (code) table (as they can be in group with the same code or out of group with a different code), so I need to run it per group and include an indication of what group it was ran with each time, so then I can filter the groups on the report page

Comment: It's hard to go further without seeing example input/output, but I think the ideal solution is one data table with employee, primary shop, and secondary shop, and two shop tables, one for primary and one for secondary.

Comment: Thanks for trying anyway. Is it not possible to wrap my whole code in a for loop of some sort? Or apply a filter on the report page that directly links to the code 100 line, so I can change it dynamically on each report?

Comment: I'm sure it is possible. It is just hard for me to mentally visualize what you are trying to do from your description.

Comment: I'll try explain the tables. So I have a shops table (contains _ID, name, code). I have an employees table (contains _ID, name). I have an employees_shops table (contains _ID, shop_ID, employee_ID and phase (secondary or primary)). Every employee has two employee_shops records, one for primary and one for secondary. I am looking up all the primary shops in each group (code) and seeing what secondary shops those employees are also linked to. But the secondary shops can belong to any group (code). In the final table I have a row for each secondary shop and a status of in group or not

Comment: And what do you want your output visual to look like?

Comment: I want a table of all the linked secondary schools. The _ID, name, code and a status of whether they are in same group or not as corresponding primary. If I am running this function in an aggregate for each group/code (rather than one at a time as i am doing now). It will need another column saying what original group/code it was ran with. Some secondaries will appear multiple times for different groups

Comment: So you want to see employees with a secondary shop outside of the shop group of their primary shop? In the format Primary Shop > Secondary Shop > Employee?

Comment: I want to see all the secondary shops linked to the employees, but with a column saying if its in same shop group or not as the employee primary. E.g - <secondaryShop1, 5 employees, in same group....secondaryShop2, 2 employees, in different group>

Comment: The code I have already essentially works, it's just I'm having to hardcode the primary group code each time for it to run per group, rather than running them all at once and having a way to split them up on the report page

Answer (score 0):

without sample data reflecting your data model it's quite difficult to provide help.
I would avoid using FILTER inside a MAXX at all. Instead I would go with set operators like
INTERSECT()/EXCEPT() finding all the shops and then use NATURALINNERJOIN or NATURALLEFTOUTERJOIN to find all the employees and the associated shops.